# React Native Pass data to another component on same file

Tags: react-native, components

I have two components and I want to pass data from one component to another component.

I have implemented different solutions but cannot solve this issue
The following is my code:

```js
class PersonalInfo extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

    }
    state = {
        FirstName: '',
        LastName: '',
        Email: '',
        DateofBirth: '',
        Gender: '',
        AgeGroup: '',
        error: {}


    }
    NextSignUp = async (data) => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate("Addressinfo", { FirstName: 'waqas' })
    }
    render() {

        return (
            <View>
                <TouchableHighlight style={[styles.buttonContainer, styles.loginButton]} onPress={() => this.NextSignUp(this.state)} >
                    <Text style={styles.loginText}>Next</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>

        );
    }
}


class AddressInfo extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isChecked: true,
            TermsConditioncheckbox: false,
            StreetAddress: '',
            City: '',
            State: '',
            ZipCode: '',
            error: {},
        }


    }
    render() {
        const { FirstName } = this.props.route.params.FirstName
        return ();
    }
}
```

how can I solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: To extract an item from an object, you have to pass the object to the right-hand side of the equals sign. like         `const { FirstName } = this.props.route.params`

Answer (score 0):

const { FirstName } = this.props.navigation.route.params;

Answer (score 0):

You can use getParam() of navigation as below

```js
const firstName = this.props.navigation.getParam('FirstName', 'Default value')
```

Comment: Try to get it in componentDidMount()